# How to take list to HTML table?

Tags: python, html, tkinter

I'm making a web scraping in Python and I'm stuck at the moment where I have to write a file to make an HTML output.

So, I have a list called checked_list that filled with:

```
['"link of the picture"', 'title event', 'date event']
```

I have tried to make `text1` and `text2` then `.write()` both of them and it's working. I can show the picture. But I need a for loop to keep reading all the index so that I can show the picture event, title event, and date event.

I've tried to use text1 then `text1 +=` to write the whole HTML and I've tried to use text1 and text2 then combine them, but I can't find a way to use for loop as it always says syntax error.

Example of the `checked_list`:

```
checked_list = ['"http://bneart.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/3fbf2374-5cb4-4229-a247-78c2582c5105-817x1024.jpg"', 'Lara Merrett: Flip side', '7th - 25th May'] -- > for 1 event

checked_list = ['"http://bneart.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Foliage-and-Structure-black_small-1024x613.jpg"', 'Helen Wyatt: I Walk the Line', '11th May - 13th July', '"http://bneart.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/3fbf2374-5cb4-4229-a247-78c2582c5105-817x1024.jpg"', 'Lara Merrett: Flip side', '7th - 25th May'] -- > 2 events
```

```
def print_planner():
checked_list = []
index = 0
html_file = open(planner_file, "w")
text1 = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Entertainment List</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>           
        '''
text2 = "<td><img src=" + str(checked_list[index]) + ">" "</td></tr>"

'''
    </table>
</body>
</html>
'''
html_file.write(text1)
html_file.write(text2)
html_file.close()
```

Any idea how can I combine for loop inside there? It's either with using only text1 or using `text1` and `text2`.

As long as it works, it's fine. If you can see the picture, It's so far I can make it. I wanted to print the title and the date underneath that.

Comment: how text2 should looks like ? in text2 should be only 1 <td><img /></td> ? or many ?

Comment: @gachdavit yeah so the text1 is the initial setup of the html file and the text2 is where I should start input checked_list to the html. that's why i split it into text1 and text2.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's exactly what you want. Just add more image extensions for you in image_exts tuple.

```
def print_planner():
    image_exts = ('.png', '.jpg', '.gif') # add valid image extensions for you
    checked_list = ['data1', 'data2', 'hi', 'picture1.png', 'picture2.png', 'picture3.jpg', 'I am python']
    checked_list = map(str, checked_list) # cast everything in str and persist results.

    text2 = ''.join(
        ['<td><img src="{}" /> </td>'.format(src) for src in checked_list for ext in image_exts if src.endswith(ext)]
    )
    text1 = '''
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Entertainment List</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                {}  
            </tr>
        </table>

        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    '''.format(text2)
    with open(planner_file, 'w') as f:
        # using with statement file-stream will be closed automatically.
        f.write(text1)
```